# Changing the color of a line with isPointInStroke

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas

I have drawn two lines with canvas and i have a mouse down event listening to the canvas,
On clicking the line, the color of that line should change. I have implemented this approach
with isPointInStroke method of canvas but the problem is all the lines drawn are highlighted.

I dont know where i was wrong. Can someone fix this issue?
Link to working [demo](https://playcode.io/364262?tabs=script.js,preview,console)
Here is what i have tried,

```
const c = document.getElementById('c');
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var onLine = false;                                // state (for demo)
ctx.moveTo(10, 10);                               // store a line on path
ctx.lineTo(220, 0);
ctx.moveTo(50, 20);                               // store a line on path
ctx.lineTo(200, 100);
ctx.lineWidth = 16;   
// line width
render();                                          // initial render

function render() {
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,300,150);
  ctx.strokeStyle = onLine ? "red" : "green";      // color based on state
  ctx.stroke();                                // stroke path
}

c.onmousedown = function(e) {
  const rect = c.getBoundingClientRect();
  const x = e.clientX - rect.left;
  const y = e.clientY - rect.top;
  onLine = ctx.isPointInStroke(x, y);
  render();
};
```

Comment: You need to define each path separately. The Path2D constructor might help a lot here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution which uses two Path2D objects to represent the lines being drawn. This makes it easier to detect clicks within a given line using `ctx.isPointInStroke(path, x, y)`, instead of `ctx.isPointInStroke(x, y)`

Note that this solution does NOT assume that the clicks are mutually exclusive. So if the lines did overlap (they don't in this case), the color of both lines would change if an overlapping area is clicked.

Also, note that colors are only toggled when a line is clicked. The color of a line remains the same if it is not clicked.

```
const c = document.getElementById('c');
const START_COLOR = "green";
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

/*Path2D objects representing the two lines */
var pathA = new Path2D();
var pathB = new Path2D();

/*Build the paths */
pathA.moveTo(10, 10);                               // store a line on path A
pathA.lineTo(220, 0);

pathB.moveTo(50, 20);                               // store a line on path B
pathB.lineTo(200, 100);

ctx.strokeStyle = START_COLOR;  

/*Booleans tracking the click state of each line */
var clickedA = false;
var clickedB = false;

/*Both lines initially set to the start color */
var colorA = START_COLOR;
var colorB = START_COLOR;

ctx.lineWidth = 16;                                 // line width


render();                                          // initial render





function render() {

  ctx.clearRect(0,0, 150, 300);

  /*Check if A was clicked, and toggle its color by setting context strokeStyle*/
  if (clickedA === true)
  {
        colorA = (colorA == "red" ? "green" : "red");  
  }

  /*Set correct color for A and draw it to canvas */
  ctx.strokeStyle = colorA;         
  ctx.stroke(pathA);


  /*Check if B was clicked, and toggle its color */
  if (clickedB === true)
  {
    colorB = (colorB == "red" ? "green" : "red");  
  }     

  /*Set correct color for B and draw it to canvas */      
  ctx.strokeStyle = colorB;   
  ctx.stroke(pathB);

  /*Reset values of clickedA and clickedB to false */
  clickedA = false;
  clickedB = false;
}

c.onmousedown = function(e) {
  const rect = c.getBoundingClientRect();
  const x = e.clientX - rect.left;
  const y = e.clientY - rect.top;

  /*Here we use the other version of isPointInStroke which has path2D 
    as first param to detect click within either stroke */
  clickedA = ctx.isPointInStroke(pathA, x, y);           

  /*Check for click within path B for a click in pathB */
  clickedB = ctx.isPointInStroke(pathB, x, y);


  render();
}
```

See JS fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/OCBiermann/orc7qdys/

Comment: Yeah sure. I'll post a pic.

Comment: Ok I updated it. New link is https://playcode.io/365298?tabs=script.js,preview, and also posted a link for js fiddle.